# issue in matching regexp in perl

Tags: perl

I am having following code

```
$str = "
   OTNPKT0553 04-02-03 21:43:46

M  X DENY

   PLNA

   /*Privilege, Login Not Active*/

;";

$val = $str =~ /[

]*([\n]?[\n]+
[\n]?)   ([^;^
]+)/s;

print "$1 and $2";
```

Getting output as

```
and PLNA
```

Why it is getting `PLNA` as output. I believe it should stop at first`\n`. I assume output should be `OTNPKT0553 04-02-03 21:43:46`

Comment: What specifically are you trying to match?  It's hard to diagnose what's going wrong without knowing exactly what your goal is.

Comment: Actually i am checking a larger regexp. I am checking in parts. Question is `([^;^
]+)` is giving output as `PLNA` but i am thinking output should be  `OTNPKT0553 04-02-03 21:43:46`

Comment: I don't think your question has much to do with the Tcl programming language…

Comment: only syntax is different. REGEXP is same in TCL and PERL. so as output If you feel it is wrong then i will remove TCL tag

Comment: Why is the first character class split over three lines?  Why don't you use the `\n` notation to represent newline in it, and what else is in there?  Are you sure `\s` doesn't cover what you need?  The `[^;^ ]` character class matches white space in some form or another; are you sure `\s` wouldn't help?  You seem to want a collection of 'not semicolon, not caret and not white space'.

Comment: Note that `[^;^\n]+` (one or more characters that aren't newlines, `;` or `^`) is probably suppose to be `[^;\n]+` (one or more characters that aren't newlines or `;`).

Comment: Note that `/s` is useless since you don't use `.`.

Comment: Don't you think you should show your *"larger regexp"* as it seems likely that it will need some work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is messy and contains a lot of redundancy.  The following steps demonstrate how it can be simplified and then it becomes more clear why it is matching `PLNA`.

1) Translating the literal new lines in your regex:

```
$val = $str =~ /[\n\n]*([\n]?[\n]+\n[\n]?)   ([^;^\n]+)/s;
```

2) Then simplifying this code to remove the redundancy:

```
$val = $str =~ /(\n{2})   ([^;^\n]+)/s;
```

So basically, the regex is looking for two new lines followed by 3 spaces.

There are three spaces before `OTNPKT0553`, but there is only a single new line, so it won't match.

The next three spaces are before `PLNA` which IS preceded by two new lines, and so matches.

Comment: Thanks but a doubt. It can also go to line `/*Privilege, Login Not Active*/`. Because `*` is a greedy one

Comment: @RobEarl No. The leading `[\n\n]*` will reduce to `[\n]*`.  That will greedily eat up all the extra new lines.  So the first capture group will only ever match its required 2 new lines.

Comment: @Nitesh The only multiplier `*` is in the leading new line character class `[\n]*`.  Yes that will match greedily, but it will only match new lines not other characters.  I stand by my step two reduction and final conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

You have a whole lot of newlines in there - some literal and some encoded as `\n`. I'm not clear how you were thinking. Did you think `\n` matched a *number* maybe? A `\d` matches a *digit*, and will also match many Unicode characters that are digits in other languages. However for simple ASCII text it works fine.

What you need is something like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "
   OTNPKT0553 04-02-03 21:43:46

M  X DENY

   PLNA

   /*Privilege, Login Not Active*/

;";

my $val = $str =~ / (\w+) \s+ ( [\d-]+ \s [\d:]+ ) /x;

print "$1 and $2";
```

**output**

```
OTNPKT0553 and 04-02-03 21:43:46
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering why it giving output as `PLNA`. My mistake if question is not clear

Comment: @Nitesh: Your question is clear, I just don't understand how you came to use a regex pattern like that which captures nothing but newlines into `$1`

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra line feed, change the regex to:

```
$str =~ /[

]*([\n]?[\n]+[\n]?)   ([^;^
]+)/s;
```

and simpler:

```
$str =~  /\n+   ([^;^\n]+)/s;
```

Comment: Your reduction is inaccurate.   If this was correct, his regex would've matched `OTNPKT0553 04-02-03 21:43:46` like he was expecting.   `\n+` should actually be `\n{2}`.